# Within CSS what is the difference between opacity:0 and display:none?

Tags: jquery, css

I am working with the jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut method and confused by exactly what it is doing. The docs state that the method affects the opacity property of the element but display:none also work to hide an element and then fade it in. Are opacity:0 and display:none the same thing? I am seeing some really choppy animations using the methods and want to understand better whats going.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`display: none` lets the element disappear. Just like it isn't present. This means your layout may change.

`opacity: 0` this one just makes your element invisible. It doesn't take any effect on your layout.

Answer (score 7):

Both cases make the element invisible, but **properties are different**:

- `opacity: 0` : **invisible**, but **takes display space** (affect the layout), and **clickable**
- `display: none` : **invisible**, **doesn't take display space**, and hence **not clickable**

Let me add a third one that is relevant in this context:

- `visibility: hidden` : **invisible**, **takes display space**, and **not clickable**

I have made an demo JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/sebastien_worms/tCbJD/

Comment: ... Maybe it's not really correct, since the DOM is not about display if I understand correctly. Thank you for pointing me the mistake, I'm editing the post.

Answer (score 2):

`opacity:0` will still allow click, hover, and other mouse events on the element. It just won't be visible to the user.

`display:none` does what it implies—the element still exists but is completely not visible, as though it's `width` and `height` are 0.

Answer (score 2):

`display: none` is like an object was removed from the page, `opacity: 0` or `visibility: none` both keep the object on the page but just makes everything clear and leaves an empty space where it was. When it's opacity: 0 you can still click on it, but i don't think the same for visibility: none.

Answer (score 2):

They will both make the text invisible, but `display: none;` will make it look like it never existed, where `opacity:0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);` will make it look like something is just missing.

For instance.

---

`display: none;`

```
This is text
<div style="display: none;">This test is invisible</div>
This is more text
```

will display as

This is text
This is more text

---

`opacity:0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);`

```
This is text
<div style="opacity:0.0; filter:alpha(opacity=0);">This test is invisible</div>
This is more text
```

will display as

This is text

This is more text

---

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Opacity affects the transparency of the object.
Display affects how the object is rendered in the web browser.

For example:

```
 This text is here!
 <div style="opacity:0">
 This text will be invisible
 </div>
 this text will be here
```

this (to the user looking at it) will make it seem like "this text is here!" and "this text will be here" have a line break between them.

and this example:

```
This text is here!
<div style="display:none">
This text will be invisible
</div>
this text will be here
```

this (to the user) will make it seem like the two visible lines are directly on top of each other with no space in between.

In JQuery, a fade in or fade out will change the Display from "none" to "block" and visa versa for the other, respectively. It will also animate the opacity from 0 to 1 smoothly within the allotted time, again visa versa for the other.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @arminb's Answer (I can't just comment on it) display:none will work in all (vaguely modern) browsers, opacity:0 has flaky support in older browsers (doesn't work in IE6, 7 or 8)

If you do need Opacity then something like this should work in all:

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

But that's messy. `display:none` is the cleanest solution which will work. `visibility:hidden` will also work in more browsers than opacity and achieves the same purpose (i.e. makes it invisible, but leaves it there)