# Tons of extra whitespace when viewed on mobile

Tags: html, css

When my website is viewed on mobile browsers, there is tons of white room to the right and bottom of the actual content of the site. I've tried to put `overflow-x: hidden` on my `<body>` to turn off the horizontal scrolling, but even that doesn't work. As far as I can see, I also don't have any elements exceeding the bounds of the screen. My site can be found [here](https://alices-march-for-equality.herokuapp.com/).

Comment: More details regarding your problem would be helpful in providing answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by

`<img class="bkgimage" src="colorfulbackground.jpg">`

In desktop version you set some css like `width:100%;` to make image fit in `div`, but in mobile version this css is replaced by `opacity: 0;`. So your image stop scaling to page width and `opacity: 0` don't disappear image from rendering, only render as fully transparent. You should use `display: none;` instead, and move `display: block;` to desktop CSS because its overwrite mobile CSS. Selectors with id (#) are more important than selectors without them.

Few related links

[Within CSS what is the difference between opacity:0 and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598969/within-css-what-is-the-difference-between-opacity0-and-displaynone)

[Does opacity:0 have exactly the same effect as visibility:hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272360/does-opacity0-have-exactly-the-same-effect-as-visibilityhidden)

https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Answer (score -1):

I can't reproduce this error with the mobile Edge browser, but maybe this meta tag could help:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```